# How to install correctly Stanford Parser in Ubuntu? (without nltk)

Tags: java, python, ubuntu, stanford-nlp, linguistics

I'm trying to install **Stanford Parser** on Ubuntu 18.04.3, purely without installing the NLTK package, but I am not sure how it's installed to be able to use it with Java or Python.

I have already downloaded the complete package and the languages I need from the official website  [Stanford Parser] [https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Download ]. 
So, I also have Java JDK and Java JRE installed, but I can't get Stanford Parser paks detected.

I'm new at this. :-|

Comment: The easiest way would be to create a maven project and add `stanford-corenlp` to maven dependencies. Otherwise read a little about java classpath, and add stanford-corenlp and models jar to your IDE's appropriate settings.

Comment: I have seen that some talk about it, but they have told me that I don't need to install the Stanford-Corenlp. I just need the full package of only the Stanford-Parser.  :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download and unzip the directory
2. `cd /path/to/stanford-parser-full-2018-10-17`
3. `export CLASSPATH=/path/to/stanford-parser-full-2018-10-17/*:`
4. `java -Xmx5g edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat "penn,typedDependencies" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz data/english-onesent.txt`

Comment: I have made your recommendations, but it gives me the following error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser`

I think this is not taking the CLASSPATH directory.

Comment: Are you running this on Linux or Windows?  Command line or an IDE ?

Comment: Your instructions working well for me, my problem was that I didn't put the path completely route for the Stanford Parser location.
Thanks a lot.
 :-D